# I messed up my zsh path for flutter install

Tags: flutter, macos, installation, terminal, zsh

I want to install flutter on my Mac m1 but I have just messed up the terminal I cannot run any command and I am new to UNIX

`Last login: Thu Feb 17 11:44:08 on ttys000 /Users/safderhussainzaidi/.zshrc:export:2: not valid in this context: $ PATH:Users/safdarhussainzaidi/simp/flutter/bin  safderhussainzaidi@Safders-MacBook-Air ~ %`

Whenever I open my terminal I get this message every time and I have messed up my terminal a lot so can someone please guide me on how I can solve this issue

Comment: paste the contents of your .zshrc file available at ``HD > Users > safdarhussainzaidi > .zshrc``

Comment: Make sure to enable ``show hidden files `` by pressing ``Cmd + Shift + .``

Comment: and the line you should have in your ``.zshrc`` should be ``export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/simp/flutter/bin"``

Answer (score 1):

This is the issue with your `.zshrc` file. You might have accidentally corrupted your `zshrc` file. One simple way to resolve the issue is make a copy of your current `.zshrc` file (the corrupted one). Then delete the file.

Since you cannot access the terminal, go to home directory via finder and press `Command + Shift + .` (period). This will reveal the hidden files. So copy (after copying, delete the `.zshrc` file) or rename the current `.zshrc` file.

Open the terminal, then it will create a new `.zshrc` file for you. Later, you could copy the relevant information (setting the path etc) from your old `.zshrc` file.

As **OMi Shah** pointed out, the issue is the way you set your path in .zshrc. So set it accordingly.

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/simp/flutter/bin"
```

Answer (score 0):

I used VS code, so <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> closes the current folder and opens your HOME folder in VS CODE. Run `open .zshrc` and paste this `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/simp/flutter/bin"`